# How to mirror part of an object but duplicate another part?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I'm making a toy train track switch. There are left and right orientations:
[image: left and right orientations]
[image]

I'd like to be able to only edit one mesh and have it be mirrored to the other orientation (currently using mirror modifier). But the connectors can't be mirrored, they have to keep the same orientation. I've achieved this so far by splitting off the connectors, doing an array modifier, and rotating/translating them into place on the mirror. This is tedious and results in multiple objects, whereas I want to be able to export each switch as a whole (STL file, in this case). I know I can apply all the modifiers, but that negates the benefit of editing both at the same time. Am I missing some best practice here? I'm a relative newbie to Blender.